# what is the maximum size (memory size) of image can be uploaded in iphone?

Tags: ios4

I m doing an application in iphone, which gets the image as input - it displays images but sometimes it doesn't. so please any one give me the information about the maximum memory size of image the iphone can display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limit i think so, may be your image format is not supported one

Comment: No...there is a limit for an image to be uploaded..., U can watch in console while uploading large images, it will display u an error, sometimes..., thanks for u reply